# How to open a HTML page in a different component in Angular with a button

Tags: html, angular

I have a angular project with multiple components. I made a button in HTML. How can I make the button open the HTML page from another component? Also when I add a new button the webpage goes blank and only displays the background.

This is for my angular project, using Webstorm.

```
<button  class="btn nav-link m-1 btn btn-success w-100"
         (click)="openToggle>
  Open page
</button>
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are asking but it sounds like reading this will help: https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: I have a button in HTML and when I click on it. It should open a HTML file in a different component. How do I do that?

Comment: You should look at Routing as Mike suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Please use routing https://angular.io/guide/router.

this.router.navigate(['/heroes']);

Answer (score 0):

You can use `navigateByUrl` or `navigate` to change your route or page when you click on your button.

```
<button  class="btn nav-link m-1 btn btn-success w-100"
     (click)="openToggle()">Open page
</button>
```

your .ts file should be like this

```
constructor(private router: Router) {}

openToggle() {
 this.router.navigateByUrl('/profile');
}
```

or

```
openToggle() {
this.router.navigate(['/profile']);
}
```